# xpath expression for when node doesn't exist?

Tags: xpath

I am dealing with some irregularities in my documents, mainly, certain nodes are present and some other times, it's not there. I want an xpath which is able to take account both situations.

For example across my documents, there are cases when span is present and when it's not there.

```
/html/body/span/div/table/tr/td/a
/html/body/div/table/tr/td/a
```

How can I express an xpath which will match both cases above ?

Comment: I don't understand why this kind of questions... Do you note that `/html//a` also would select the `a` elements in both cases?

Comment: yes but `//` will simply return ALL links on the page, where as I would like links that "roughly" follow some structure as above....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `//` selector will search arbitrarily deep. This will work with or without the span (it will also find divs inside of other tags besides body and span):

```
/html/body//div/table/tr/td/a
```

You can join two result-sets together using the union `|` operator:

```
/html/body/span/div/table/tr/td/a |
/html/body/div/table/tr/td/a
```

You could use use some crazy filtering to try to do it all in one path. Untested:

```
/html/body/descendant-or-self::*[self::body or self::span/parent::body]/div/table/tr/td/a
```

Comment: with the crazy filtering, it seems to select both body AND span (when it's present). Is it possible to make it select span only ? When span is not present, it selects body as it should.